# Using registry keys, determine if Active Directory Domain Services is running on a host

Tags: windows, active-directory, registry, adlds

I would like to know if it is possible to determine if Active Directory Domain Services is running on a host by looking at certain registry keys. I'm also trying to do the same for Active Directory Lightweight Directory Service.

So far research has lead me to look for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\^SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\ADAM_.*$` to see if AD LDS is installed, however I would like to know if the service is currently running, or alternatively, if this is possible to achieve.

Comment: Please narrow your questions to one question per question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can check if the service is running on the server/machine via powershell

```
get-service NTDS
```

(Active Directory Domain Services) get the status or if it exist.
Also

```
get-service ADWS
```

to get the status of the ADDS ans AD LDS.

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  ADWS               Active Directory Web Services
```

Please write what you want to achieve and how you want to run this.
How you want to be notified if the service is not running.
If you need a csv or a txt import with the server names (list).

Please provide more information or use this command it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, those powershell commands retrieve the information I'm looking for. 

I'm trying to retrieve the same information that the above powershell commands produce, but by only using regedit. If I could open the Registry Editor and navigate to a specific registry key that specifies whether or not Active Directory Domain Service is running, that would perfect. Do you know if this is possible? I know there are keys that specify that ADDS is installed, I'm trying to determine if there is a key that specifies if it's running or not

Comment: You can determine the type of product from the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductType

WinNT = workstation
LanmanNT = domain controller
ServerNT = member server

Then HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ADWS\
there is a start flag but I don't know how it works.

I would prefer the powershell command.